# mvc controller creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

While creating an MVC3 project, I got this problem. I created Movies.cs and while creating the Controller for this Model, I did the following.

- Right-click the Controllers folder, and select Add and Controller
- Set controller name to MoviesController
- Select template: Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework
- Select model class: Movies (McvDemo.Models)
- Select data context class: MovieContext (McvDemo.Models)
- Select views Razor (CSHTML)
- Click Add.

It processed for a while and got me this error.

> Unable to retrieve metadata gor "MvcDemo.Models.Movies". Unable to
>      find the requested.NET framework Data provider. It may not be
>      installed.

What does that means? If anyone could point me the answer.

Comment: http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/unable-to-find-requested-net-framework.html

Comment: What database are you using, Sql server or Sql CE or LocalDB? Also can you put your connection string, and entity framework node from web.config.

Comment: I am using SQL server with visual studio 2010.

Comment: connection string is <connectionStrings>
    <add  name="MovieDBContext"
          connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>    
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I think the problem is with "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", if I am correct!!